# WooCommerce 2.0: product attribute values disappear after update

Tags: php, wordpress, upgrade, woocommerce, taxonomy

I updated WordPress to 3.6.1 and WooCoommerce to 2.0.14. After the update a bunch of my product attribute's values disappeared from the admin and front-end. However they still show up in the database. I disabled all other plugins changed to the default theme but there is no change.

The attributes affected had taxonomy meta data attached to them and am wondering if this isn't causing the problem. I am using this class to add meta fields to the attributes. https://github.com/bainternet/Tax-Meta-Class

Any ideas on possible causes?

**Edit**

It seems the updates have affected the way WP handles taxonomy slugs. My taxonomies are slugged `conf_part1`, `conf_part2`, etc (I still see them this was in the taxonomy list). For its own purpose, WooCommerce then renames them to `pa_conf_part1`.

On WP 3.5 when I access a taxonomy, the URL is `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=pa_conf_part1` however in 3.6 it's `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=pa_conf-veste`. This breaks my whole site as I have a pretty complex product configuration module which relies on this convention.

Has there been a change in WP 3.6 or WC 2.0 which affects taxonomy slug names? Any ideas on possible causes?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by removing the underscores from all attribute slugs (e.g change conf_part1 to confpart1) and run an upgrade script on the postmeta table - (e.g. UPDATE xx_postmeta SET meta_key = REPLACE(meta_key, 'attribute_pa_conf_part1', 'attribute_pa_confpart1')) before the Woocommerce upgrade.